# WPF MVVM Binding a ContentConrol's ContentTemplate's StaticResource

Tags: wpf, mvvm

The code in my UserControl's Resource section:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="BillingLevel" DataType="{x:Type local:ViewBillingLevel}">
        <local:ViewBillingLevel Width="Auto" Height="Auto"/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="Suburb" DataType="{x:Type local:ViewSuburb}">
        <local:ViewSuburb Width="Auto" Height="Auto" />
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

The section I want to do the binding in:

```
<ContentControl Grid.Row="2" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource Suburb}" Margin="5" />
```

Something like:

```
<ContentControl Grid.Row="2" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource={Binding myDataTemplateKey}}" Margin="5" />
```

So I can switch between the DataTemplates in the C# code behind.
I don't know if this is possible or how this can be achieved in another way.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to switch datatemplates for the same content type or something else? Are we talking about 2-3 distinct templates or about *many*? For managing a low amount of templates based on some value, I might write a `DataTrigger` based answer but this would not be useful in a more generic context with many different templates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `ContentTemplateSelector` property and a `DataTemplateSelector` class to implement custom template-selection logic: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.contenttemplateselector(v=vs.110).aspx

Or you could use implicit data templates. Remove the `x:Key` attributes:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ViewBillingLevel}">
        <local:ViewBillingLevel Width="Auto" Height="Auto"/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ViewSuburb}">
        <local:ViewSuburb Width="Auto" Height="Auto" />
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

The appropriate `DataTemplate` will then be automatically applied as you set or bind the `Content` property of the `ContentControl` to a `ViewBillingLevel`/`ViewSuburb` object.

Comment: Implicit templates are amazing, this is the answer you want @Elmer.  The only reason not to use them here would be if you didn't know all the possible templates at design time.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is  a `DataTemplateSelector`

C#

```
   public class MyTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
    {
        public DataTemplate BillingLevel
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public DataTemplate Suburb
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
        {
            if(item is ViewBillingLevel)
            {
                return BillingLevel;
            }

            if(item is ViewSuburb)
            {
                return Suburb;
            }

            return base.SelectTemplate(item, container);
        }
    }
```

XAML

```
<UserControl.Resources>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="BillingLevel">

    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="Suburb">

    </DataTemplate>

    <selector:MyTemplateSelector x:Key="MyTemplateSelector"
                                 Suburb="{StaticResource Suburb}"
                                 BillingLevel="{StaticResource BillingLevel}"
                                 />


</UserControl.Resources>
```

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding MyV}"
                ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource MyTemplateSelector}"
                />
```

`MyV` is your ViewModel to bind - So the `DataTemplateSelector` decides what template to use.

**Extendend:**

If you have only one `ViewModel` - you could use a Property to switch Templates. For example

```
public class MyTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate BillingLevel
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public DataTemplate Suburb
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {


MyViewModel value = item as MyViewModel;

        if(value.IsSuburb)
        {
            return Suburb;
        }
        else
        {
            return BillingLevel;
        }

        return base.SelectTemplate(item, container);
    }
}
```